# My state is populated with array of objects but length is zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react functional component and i have state which stores array

```
const [channelList, setChannelList] = useState([]);
```

This function updates the state after submisson of an input form and state updates sucessfully

```
const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const channelName = inputChannelNameRef.current.value;
    const channelId = inputChannelIdRef.current.value;
    setChannelList([
      ...channelList,
      {
        rowId: channelList.length + 1,
        channelName: channelName,
        channelId: channelId,
        template: deleteBtn, // delete button component which perform row delete action
      },
    ]);
    console.log(channelList.length); 
  };
```

This function is called on clicking the delete button through passing row ID

```
const deleteRow = (rowId) => {
    console.log(channelList.length); // logging zero every time
}
```

This deleteRow() function was not working so i console.log the state length then i found that it is returning 0 every time but my rows are showing perfectly fine. Why it is giving zero when it has number of objects in it. In function handleFormSubmit() i am getting length of channelList perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm going to say this once, like I probably will say it many times later: Many people misunderstand how states work. A state may update, but the code will not recognise that the state has updated and hence will only read the value of the state as it was when the file was initially ran.

Comment: More context of the application is needed in order to find the specific problem. Please post the entire component, and most importantly the context in which the deleteRow function exists. This is probably a closure problem but we need to see the entire component to answer that

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  Currently nothing in the code shown ever invokes `deleteRow`.  And it sounds like your debugging observations are wrong and likely based on a false assumption somewhere, because there is no way the `console.log(channelList.length)` operation in `handleFormSubmit` is outputting the new updated length of the array because that state change hasn't been processed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use prev:

```
const obj = {
        rowId: channelList.length + 1,
        channelName: channelName,
        channelId: channelId,
        template: deleteBtn,
      },

setChannelList((prev) => {...prev,...obj})
```

Answer (score 0):

State changes are asynchronous, so they will not show on a console.log immediately.

If you want to check length of the state by logging it to the console, you can place your console.log in a useEffect hook with your state as the dependency.

This will log the state array length every time channelList is set.

It is a bit strange you aren't seeing the length on the deleteRow Function, unless you are setting state immediately before the console.log.

Edit: reading again, you shouldn't be seeing an updated channelList.length when trying to log it in handleFormSubmit. You are likely seeing the length prior to the state change.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(channelList.length);
}, [channelList])
```